# how to shuffle a letters of array in android?

Tags: android, arrays, string, random, shuffle

```
String arrAnimal[] = {"cat","dog","parrot","fish"};
```

I need to shuffle each word and set it to TextView, when click button wanna go through each element(see Shuffeled elements).

Comment: so `tca, gdo, prrota, sfih`, or `fish, dog, cat, parrot`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Random shuffling of an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1519736/random-shuffling-of-an-array)

Comment: "tca, gdo, prrota, sfih"  like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete working code,

```
String[] animals = {"cat","dog","parrot","fish"};
for (int i = 0; i < animals.length; ++i) {
    List<Character> letters = new ArrayList<>(animals[i].length());
    for (char c : animals[i].toCharArray()) {
        letters.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(letters);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (char c : letters) {
        builder.append(c);
    }
    animals[i] = builder.toString();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(animals));
```

Outputs: `[tca, ogd, roptar, sifh]`

EDIT: To print line by line, change the last line to,

```
for (String s : animals) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Comment: Thnkx Hindol.
Can i get this out put one by one?

Answer (score 0):

**Get the random word:**

private var currentWord = getRandomWord()

**ArrayList to store the data:**

```
val dashboardList: List<String> =
    listOf("den",
        "music",
        "podcast",
        "library",
        "gallary",
        "work")
```

**Creating a separate method to get the random word from the ArrayList:**

```
  private fun getRandomWord(): String {
        val word = allWordsList.random().toCharArray()
        word.shuffle()
        return String(word)
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Collections.shuffle( )

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("cat");
list.add("dog");
list.add("parrot");
list.add("fish");

Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: How to change word order of elements.(letters)